# MakeFile compiling all the files even if those were already compiled and weren't touched after that

Tags: c, makefile

This is my makefile

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -g -lm

SHELL=/bin/bash

CFILES=$(wildcard *.c)
OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.c,%,$(CFILES))

.PHONY: clean status all

all: $(OBJECTS)

#%:%.c
#   gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

$(OBJECTS): $(CFILES)
    @echo "Running : $@ -> $^"
#   gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(patsubst %,%.c,$@) 

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS)

status:
    @git status
    @git diff --stat

push: clean
    git push
```

when i am using `%:%.c`(rule commented in Makefile) it is running fine. By all of this i can only think is that rule **`$(OBJECTS): $(CFILES)`** is somehow thinks that any target in OBJECTS depends on all of the values in $(CFILES).

So whenever it is building any single binray, it sees that it depends on all CFILES so it recompile any c file if anyone of those is modified.

So i want to know is there a better way to write the rule **`$(OBJECTS): $(CFILES)`**, if that is causing the issue. Otherwise If this rule isn't the culprit than what is causing this. I know i can use **`%:%.c`** but i think it can cause some problems, as this rule will also holds true for `something.h`.

**I am new with Makefiles, So it would be helpful if you elaborate the cause also, So in future i can prevent that**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct.  When you write:

```
foo bar biz : foo.c bar.c biz.c
        # do something
```

(which is what make sees after it expands the variables), make interprets that as:

```
foo : foo.c bar.c biz.c
        # do something
bar : foo.c bar.c biz.c
        # do something
biz : foo.c bar.c biz.c
        # do something
```

Your question is a little confusing because you're using the term "objects", which usually means object files (`foo.o`), instead of binaries or executables.

Anyway, you can do what you want safely with [static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Pattern.html):

```
$(OBJECTS): % : %.c
        @echo "Running : $< -> $@"
#       gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Comment: oh i actually just copied this makefile from another directory where i was creating objects i modified few things but just ignored the variable names, and that also confused me while writing question. Sorry if it created some misunderstanding :-)

Comment: You should never ignore naming: naming is the single most important thing about writing code :)